# Add Text(Form)Field input to a list

Tags: list, flutter, textfield

Got a question for my Flutter App:

I have a List:

```
List<Item> tags = <Item>[
   Item(
     "name",
     Colors.red,
   ),
   Item(
     "Cooking",
     Colors.red,
   ),
   Item(
     "Sport",
     Colors.red,
   ),
 ];
```

and a TextFormField

```
   TextFormField(
     controller: tagController
```

how do I manage to add the Text I entered in the Formfield to the list?
They are in different StatefulWidgets.

Comment: what do you mean by saying 'They are in different StatefulWidgets.' ?

Comment: You can achieve this using `provider`.
Working on it, will share soon InShaALLAH :)

Comment: I have updated my answer, review points 2 and 4.
Using consumer is a better option since it prevents whole Stateful widget from rebuilding, hence improves the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provider is a great stateManagement solution for flutter and I have solved you problem using provider. Follow these steps carefully to make sure you implement it correctly.

1. Start by adding `Provider` to `pubspec.yaml`

   ```
   provider: ^4.3.3
   ```
2. Create a notifier class that extends `ChangeNotifier`

   ```
   class ItemListNotifier extends ChangeNotifier{

       List<Item> tags = <Item>[
                     Item(
                         "name",
                         Colors.red,
                        ),
                     Item(
                         "Cooking",
                         Colors.red,
                        ),
                     Item(
                        "Sport",
                        Colors.red,
                         ),
                      ];

       void add(Item item){

       tags.add(item);
       notifyListeners(); //Rebuilds the Stateful widget on updating list
     }
   }
   ```
3. Wrap you `MaterialApp` inside `ChangeNotifierProvider`

   ```
   class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {

     return ChangeNotifierProvider<ItemListNotifier>(

               create: (context) => ItemListNotifier(),
               child: MaterialApp(
               title: 'Flutter Demo',
               theme: ThemeData(
                         primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
                         visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
                     ),
               home: ScreenWithList(),
           )
        );
      }
   }
   ```
4. Inside you `statefulWidget` with list named `tags` access the notifier's value using a `Consumer` that rebuilds every time the list gets updated and prevents the whole screen  from rebuilding.

   ```
   class ScreenWithList extends StatefulWidget {
       @override
       _ScreenWithListState createState() => _ScreenWithListState();
    }

   class _ScreenWithListState extends State<ScreenWithList> {

   List<Item> tags = <Item>[
    Item(
       "name",
       Colors.red,
     ),
     Item(
       "Cooking",
       Colors.red,
     ),
     Item(
       "Sport",
       Colors.red,
     ),
   ];

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(),
     body: Center(child: Consumer<ItemListNotifier>(
   builder: (context, list, child) {

     print('Rebuilt');
     return ListView.builder(

         itemCount: list?.tags?.length ?? 0,
         itemBuilder: (context, index) {
       return Text(list?.tags[index]?.name ?? '');
                       }
                  );
              },
           )
       ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
     child: Icon(
         Icons.arrow_forward,
       ),
     onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: 
      (context) => ScreenWithFormField()))
         ),
      );
    }
   }
   ```
5. Now update your list from `statefulWidget` by using `Provider` to access `add` function of `ItemListNotifier`.

   ```
   FloatingActionButton(
       child: Icon(Icons.add),
       onPressed: () => Provider.of<ItemListNotifier>(context, listen: false).add(Item(tagController.text.trim(), Colors.red)),
     ),
   ```

**What's happening here?**

Every time you update the list using `ItemListNotifier's` `add` method, it rebuilds the `Consumer<ItemListNotifier`.